# JRE and Java Compiled version mismatch Visual Code Studio

Tags: java

I've ran a program and after updating java, I'm getting when trying to run any code (compiling works just fine). I've looked at people who have had similar problems, but they seemed to mostly just state the problem thats happening, and not given me too many ideas on how to fix it.

I tried reinstalling java first, and that didn't seem to do anything. Next I looked at the JRE itself, but it was set to auto-update. Just to make sure I tried looking for updates again, but nothing came up. I've also tried the basics of restarting the computer and Visual Code Studio. The biggest thing I havn't tried messing around with is my JDK, because I frankly don't know too much about how to set it up and am worried I might break it.

```
c:\Users\kmaaf\Desktop\Coding Homework\PP3>java BenchmarkTimer
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: BenchmarkTimer has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Even earlier today, the program I was working with was running fine. It was only pretty much exactly after the update anything went awry. Thanks for any help or tips you can give me in advance!

EDIT: I am using command prompt to try and run my code through. Using the command line it says my version of java is 1.8.0_211-b12, while my JDK claims to be 11.0.02

Comment: Java class version 52.0 means java 8 and java class version 55.0 means java 11. How many versions of java are installed? It is possible to install several different java versions on one computer, The error message means `BenchmarkTimer` was compiled for java 11 but _Visual Code Studio_ is configured for java 8.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Is `BenchmarkTimer` your code?  Did you compile it yourself prior to the "event" that caused the problems?  Do you have Java 8 installed?  Do you have Java 11 installed?  Which version of Java is VCS configured to use?  Have you checked the "Setting the JDK" (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) to see how VCS Java finds the JDK to use?  Are you using the same JDK to run the code from the command line?

Comment: @Abra - It is not clear that that error message comes from VSC.  It looks like a command prompt to me, which could mean that the problem is with the version of the `java` command that is on the command prompt's effective PATH.

Comment: I've tried recompiling afterwards. I havn't changed the JDK I'm using since the update. Opening the release notes on my JDK, it says version 11.0.02. Also yes, I'm using command prompt; I'll update my question to reflect that. Typing java -version into the command prompt gives me java version "1.8.0_211". There seems to be a discrepancy here, but I'm not really sure how to fix it. The version my JRE seems to be running is 1.8.0_211 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it out! Thanks for your help! For some reason, I had multiple copies of java hiding around on my computer; deleting them all and then reinstalling managed to fix everything. Thanks everybody who lent me a hand!